# Align buttons and inputs in Dash

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Dash app and I need to align two inputs and two buttons in two rows. Now I have this
[image]

I would like to obtain the button 'Download ClinicalTrial.gov info' next two the input 'Insert the filename for RCT info...' as in the first row. Here is my code:

```
html.Div([
                   dcc.Input(id='input-to-save1', placeholder="Insert the filename for DB...", type='text',
                                 pattern=r"^[A-Za-z].*", style={'width': '250px','height':'25px'}),
               ],style={'display': 'inline-block',"margin-top":"30px","margin-left":"20px",'verticalAlign': 'middle',"font-family": "Helvetica"}),
               
html.Div([
                   html.Button('Download DB info', id='download_data', n_clicks=0,
                              style={'marginLeft': '10%', 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%',
                                     "fontSize": "1em",
                                     "background-color": "white", "color": "black", "border-radius": "4px",
                                     "border": "2px solid dodgerblue"}),
               ],
                  style={'width': '190px', 'height': '40px',"margin-left":"15px","margin-top": "30px",
                         'display': 'inline-block','verticalAlign': 'middle',"font-family": "Helvetica"}
               ),
html.Div([
                      dcc.Input(id='input-to-save2', placeholder="Insert the filename for RCT info...", type='text',
                                pattern=r"^[A-Za-z].*", style={'width': '250px', 'height': '25px'}),
                  ], style={"margin-top": "30px", "margin-left": "20px",'display': 'inline-block',
                            'verticalAlign': 'middle', "font-family": "Helvetica"}),

html.Div([
                      html.Button('Download ClinicalTrial.gov info', id='rct_button', n_clicks=0,
                                  style={'marginLeft': '10%','width': '80%', 'height': '80%',
                                         "fontSize": "1em",
                                         "background-color": "white", "color": "black", "border-radius": "4px",
                                         "border": "2px solid dodgerblue"}),

                  ],
                      style={'width': '300px', 'height': '40px', "margin-left": "15px","margin-top": "30px",
                             'display': 'inline-block','verticalAlign': 'middle', "font-family": "Helvetica"}
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem in following code. The output is visible on the following image.

[image]

You should provide more info about your current CSS styles.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Input(
                    id="input-to-save1",
                    placeholder="Insert the filename for DB...",
                    type="text",
                    pattern=r"^[A-Za-z].*",
                    style={"width": "250px", "height": "25px"},
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "display": "inline-block",
                "margin-top": "30px",
                "margin-left": "20px",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
                "font-family": "Helvetica",
            },
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Button(
                    "Download DB info",
                    id="download_data",
                    n_clicks=0,
                    style={
                        "marginLeft": "10%",
                        "width": "80%",
                        "height": "80%",
                        "fontSize": "1em",
                        "background-color": "white",
                        "color": "black",
                        "border-radius": "4px",
                        "border": "2px solid dodgerblue",
                    },
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "width": "190px",
                "height": "40px",
                "margin-left": "15px",
                "margin-top": "30px",
                "display": "inline-block",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
                "font-family": "Helvetica",
            },
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Input(
                    id="input-to-save2",
                    placeholder="Insert the filename for RCT info...",
                    type="text",
                    pattern=r"^[A-Za-z].*",
                    style={"width": "250px", "height": "25px"},
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "margin-top": "30px",
                "margin-left": "20px",
                "display": "inline-block",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
                "font-family": "Helvetica",
            },
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Button(
                    "Download ClinicalTrial.gov info",
                    id="rct_button",
                    n_clicks=0,
                    style={
                        "marginLeft": "10%",
                        "width": "80%",
                        "height": "80%",
                        "fontSize": "1em",
                        "background-color": "white",
                        "color": "black",
                        "border-radius": "4px",
                        "border": "2px solid dodgerblue",
                    },
                ),
            ],
            style={
                "width": "300px",
                "height": "40px",
                "margin-left": "15px",
                "margin-top": "30px",
                "display": "inline-block",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
                "font-family": "Helvetica",
            },
        ),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Also consider using external stylesheet instead of puting CSS style directy into your code.

Comment: From this code, are you able two put the things in two rows? 
1st row ---input----button---  

2nd row ---input----button---

Comment: I recommend you to try https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai especially if you do not have CSS experience, you can create better looking apps with less CSS code.

Comment: Please use the comments to ask for additional information.